# Native Query With Spring's JdbcTempate

Tags: spring

I'm using spring's JdbcDaoSupport for making data base call. I want to execure native query (sql query) for retrieving data. Do we have any API available in JdbcTemplate for native query? I used queryForObject but it throws exception if there is no data whereas i was expecting it to return back null if it couldn't find data.

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by "non-native" query.  JdbcTemplate etc are all using SQL.  Are you simply talking about how to handle empty result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many options available for executing native sql with [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).  The linked documentation contains plenty of methods that take native sql, and usually some sort of callback handler, which will accomplish exactly what you are looking for.  A simple one that comes to mind is [`query(String sql, RowCallbackHandler callback)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler%29).

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from mytable where something > 3", new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) {
        //this will be called for each row.  DO NOT call next() on the ResultSet from in here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring JdbcTemplate's queryForObject method expects your SQL to return exactly one row. If the there are no rows returned or if there are more than 1 row returned it will throw a org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException. You will have to wrap the call to queryForObject with a try catch block to handle IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException and return null if the exception is thrown

e.g.

```
try{
   return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(...);
}catch(IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e){
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me too, it shows 3 rows, expected 1, while in reality it was only one row, I could not get it, and replaced with other code as below:

```
ProductReportStatsDTO reportStats = new ProductReportStatsDTO();
jdbcSpringManager.getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql.toString(),new RowCallbackHandler() {
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) {
                try {
                    reportStats.setSerialQty(rs.getLong(1));
                    reportStats.setProductQty(rs.getBigDecimal(2));
                    reportStats.setTotalPrice(rs.getBigDecimal(3));
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
```